# Define an array even if no checkboxes are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<form id="download">
  <label>
    <input name="docs" id="doc1" value="doc1" type="checkbox">File 1
  </label>          
  <label>
    <input name="docs" id="doc2" value="doc2" type="checkbox">File 2
  </label>          
  <button class="button" type="submit">Download</button>            
</form>
```

And the following JQuery:

```
$(function () {

  $("#download").on("submit", function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this);

    console.log($form.serializeToJSON());

    $.ajax({
      url: "/download",
      data: JSON.stringify($form.serializeToJSON()),
      dataType: "json",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      type: "post"
    })
    .done(function (data, status, xhr) { })
    .fail(function (xhr, status, error) { });

  });
});
```

When I select the two checkboxes I get the following on the console:

```
Object { names: [ "doc1", "doc2" ] }
```

And if I select only one checkbox I get:

```
Object { names: "doc1" }
```

I need "names" to be always an array as the back-end is expecting it.

So if I select only one I would get:

```
Object { names: [ "doc1" ] }
```

Or if I don't select any checkboxes then:

```
Object { names: [] }
```

What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Custom configuration is probably your best bet here.

Comment: So I should check if there is no docs defined or if there is only one item? How can I check if there is only one item selected before serialization?

Comment: I think Barmar's answer covers that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a check in your code:

```
formData = $form.serializeToJSON()
if (!formData.docs) {
    formData.docs = [];
} else if (typeof formData.docs == "string") {
    formData.docs = [formData.docs];
}
$.ajax({
  url: "/download",
  data: JSON.stringify(formData),
  dataType: "json",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  type: "post"
})
.done(function (data, status, xhr) { })
.fail(function (xhr, status, error) { });
```

Comment: Your code only considers when there is no checkbox selected. But when there is only one I also need to be an array and it is sending as a string. Check my initial question: Object { names: "doc1" }

Comment: Try using array-style names for the form fields: `name="docs[]"`

Comment: OK, then just add a check for it being a string and change it to an array. I've updated the code.

Comment: BTW, you don't need `Accept: application/json`. jQuery does that automatically when you use `dataType: 'json'`.